# Finding paths in a json tree in python

Tags: python, json

I have a json tree of the form

```
{"reply": 0, "id": 30, "children": [{"reply": 0, "id": 451, "children": []}, {"reply": 0, "id": 307, "children": []}, {"reply": 0, "id": 276, "children": []}, {"reply": 0, "id": 253, "children": []}]}
```

I want to get all the paths starting from root to the leaf of the json tree.
For this I am using

```
import json
f=open('tree_json','r')
def paths(tree, cur=()):
         if not tree:
            yield cur
         else:
            for n, s in tree.items():
                for path in paths(s, cur+(n,)):
                   yield path
for line in f:
    tree=json.loads(line)
   print list(paths(tree,(0,)))
```

But, I am not able to print the paths in a tree. The output I want is:
     {30,451},{30,307},{30,276}. I am getting

```
    for n, s in tree.items():
     AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: First of all, don't define a function inside a loop.

Comment: Second of all, what output do you want and what output are you getting?

Comment: @cyphase : Editted the question. error is <generator object paths at 0x7f4983842d20>

Comment: That's not an error, that's the return value of `paths(tree,0)`. Try `print list(paths(tree,0))`.

Comment: You should include the output you're getting in the question.

Comment: I think you want paths(tree, (0,)).  Your cursor is supposed to be a tuple, but you're passing an int.

Comment: @saulspatz : Fixed that. But now getting attribute error. please find in question

Comment: @user299662 The answer from Cyphase below shows you how to do it.  The biggest problem with your code, I think, is that you aren't picking out the id fields that you want to print or the children nodes that give the subtrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, but the "error" you were getting isn't an error; it's the value returned by `path(tree, 0)`, which is a generator. You need to wrap it in `list()` to force it to evaluate itself. That said, if you do that, you're going to run into several bugs. And even if you fix the surface bugs, your code isn't going to give you the result you want.

This code will do what you're trying to do:

```
import pprint


def paths(tree):
    if not tree['children']:
        yield (tree['id'],)
    else:
        for child in tree['children']:
            for descendant in paths(child):
                yield (tree['id'],) + descendant

tree = {
    'reply': 0,
    'id': 30,
    'children': [
        {'reply': 0, 'id': 451, 'children': []},
        {'reply': 0, 'id': 307, 'children': []},
        {'reply': 0, 'id': 276, 'children': []},
        {'reply': 0, 'id': 253, 'children': [
            {'reply': 0, 'id': 600, 'children': []},
            {'reply': 0, 'id': 700, 'children': []},
            {'reply': 0, 'id': 800, 'children': []},
            {'reply': 0, 'id': 900, 'children': []},
        ]}
        ]
    }

pprint.pprint(list(paths(tree)))
```

Output:

```
[(30, 451),
 (30, 307),
 (30, 276),
 (30, 253, 600),
 (30, 253, 700),
 (30, 253, 800),
 (30, 253, 900)]
```

Comment: @user299662, you're welcome. You should upvote/accept answers that help you :). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers